# split a string and concatenate values from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, str-replace

lstA looks like this:

```
["y1","y2","y3"]
```

and lstB looks like this:

```
["xx5, folder, 20-1-1", "xx6, appPath, 20-1-1", "xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4"]
```

All items are strings. Lengths of the lists are the same.

I want to iterate through each item of **lstB** and replace the first item before `,` with the element from lstA respectively.

At the end, **lstB** should look like this:

```
["y1, folder, 20-1-1", "y2, appPath, 20-1-1", "y3, Resolve, 23-1-4"]
```

First, I can iterate through lstB, split the string  by , to obtain the value of the first item (for example "xx5"). Then, I can replace this with the respective element in lstA. However, I am not sure how I can replace since lstA is separate.

```
for i in lstB:
    toBeReplaced = i.split(',')[0]
    totalName = i.replace(toBeReplaced, lstA[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simplified method if you're new to programming.

- code:

```
a = ["y1","y2","y3"]
b = ["xx5, folder, 20-1-1", "xx6, appPath, 20-1-1", "xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4"]
List = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp = b[i].split(',')
    temp[0] = a[i]
    List.append((',').join(temp))
```

- output:
  `['y1, folder, 20-1-1', 'y2, appPath, 20-1-1', 'y3, Resolve, 23-1-4']`

Answer (score 1):

Split and join the items of both list, can be done in a short list comprehension:

```
lstA = ["y1","y2","y3"]
lstB = ["xx5, folder, 20-1-1", "xx6, appPath, 20-1-1", "xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4"]

lstB = [','.join((a, *b.split(',')[1:])) for a, b in zip(lstA, lstB)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the second list with an index variable `i` and replace the 3 first characters with the corresponding value from first list with `[:]` string slicing operator:

```
l = ["y1","y2","y3"]
l1 = ["xx5, folder, 20-1-1", "xx6, appPath, 20-1-1", "xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4"]

for i in range(len(l1)):
    l1[i] = (l[i] + l1[i][3:])
print(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
['y1, folder, 20-1-1', 'y2, appPath, 20-1-1', 'y3, Resolve, 23-1-4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be easily achieved using `zip`

```
a=["y1","y2","y3"]
b=["xx5, folder, 20-1-1", "xx6, appPath, 20-1-1", "xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4"]
print(b)
for i,(a_,b_) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    b[i]=b_.replace(b_.split(",")[0], a_)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
before=['xx5, folder, 20-1-1', 'xx6, appPath, 20-1-1', 'xx7, Resolve, 23-1-4']
after=['y1, folder, 20-1-1', 'y2, appPath, 20-1-1', 'y3, Resolve, 23-1-4']
```